# Tikz picture with multiple boxes and brackets

Tags: tikz-pgf

Trying to create a tikz picture attached below. Please advice for the remaining part.

```
\documentclass{standalone}      
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.25cm]   
    \node (Chap1) [startstop] {This is the text for box one};
    \node (Chap2) [startstop, below of=Chap1] {This is the text for box two};
    \node (Chap3) [startstop, below of=Chap2, node distance=3cm] {This is the text for box three};
    \node (Chap4) [startstop, below of=Chap3] {This is the text for box four};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another solution ... defined are two styles (`box` and `startstop`) for nodes, with overdrawing white lines is simulated brackets:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 2mm,
   box/.style = {text width=1.8cm, align=center, below=1mm},
startstop/.style = {rectangle, draw, semithick, rounded corners=3mm,
                minimum width=#1, minimum height=1cm},
startstop/.default = 6cm
                    ]
\node (Chap1) [startstop]                   {This is the text for box one};
\node (Chap2) [startstop, below=of Chap1]   {This is the text for box two};
%
\node (Text3-2) [startstop=15mm, below=6mm of Chap2]    {Text 2};
\node (Text3-1) [startstop=15mm, left =of Text3-2]      {Text 1};
\node (Text3-3) [startstop=15mm, right=of Text3-2]      {Text 3};
%
\node (Text3-1-label) [box] at (Text3-1.south) {Text in multiple lines};
\node (Text3-2-label) [box] at (Text3-2.south) {Text in multiple lines};
\node (Text3-3-label) [box] at (Text3-3.south) {Text in multiple lines};
%
\node (Chap3) [startstop, inner xsep=0pt,
               fit=(Chap1.west |- Text3-1.north)
                   (Chap1.east |- Text3-3-label.south)] {};
\draw[white, line width=2pt]
    ([yshift=-9mm] Chap3.west) -- ++ (0,18mm)
    ([yshift=-9mm] Chap3.east) -- ++ (0,18mm);
%
\node (Chap4) [startstop, below=of Chap3] {This is the text for box four};
\node (Chap5) [startstop, below=of Chap4] {This is the text for box five};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possibility using `fit`. I also load the `positioning` library. This allows one to put the "Text 2" node 6mm below `Chap1`, such that, after setting the inner width of the `fit` node to 1mm, the distance matches the other distances between chapter, namely 0.5mm.

```
\documentclass{standalone}      
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning,fit}
\tikzset{startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=6cm,
minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm]   
    \node (Chap1) [startstop] {This is the text for box one};
    \node (Chap2) [startstop, below=of Chap1] {This is the text for box two};
    \node (Text3-2) [startstop, below=0.6cm of Chap2,minimum width=1.5cm] {Text 2};
    \node (Text3-1) [startstop, left=0.3cm of Text3-2,minimum width=1.5cm] {Text 1};
    \node (Text3-3) [startstop, right=0.3cm of Text3-2,minimum width=1.5cm] {Text 3};
    \node (Text3-1-label) [below=1mm of Text3-1),text width=1.8cm,align=center]{Text in
    multiple lines};
    \node (Text3-2-label) [below=1mm of Text3-2),text width=1.8cm,align=center]{Text in
    multiple lines};
    \node (Text3-3-label) [below=1mm of Text3-3),text width=1.8cm,align=center]{Text in
    multiple lines};
    \node (Chap3) [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=6cm, 
    draw=black,fit=(Text3-1) (Text3-1-label) (Text3-3-label),inner sep=1mm]{};
    \node (Chap4) [startstop, below=of Chap3] {This is the
    text for box fout};
    \node (Chap5) [startstop, below=of Chap4] {This is the text for box five};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]